# How can I see stl list values in gdb

Tags: linux, eclipse, debugging

I'm using Eclipse, and when I debug, the values of the list variables are unreadable and cryptic. How can I see those values? 
I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB 7 has support for python scripting which can be used to write pretty printers. For STL, the pretty printers need to understand the details of the implementation, so the pretty printers definitions must be supplied as part the standard library implementation.

For libstdc++, you can get a copy of the pretty printers from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py), though you probably want to track down the specific version of that file that matches your particular libstdc++ version.

You will need to do some work to educate your copy of GDB about this file, probably via the gdb 'source' command, but once you have convinced GDB to load it you should be able to pretty print many STL data structures, std::list included.

Comment: GDB by itself doesn't know how to walk an STL list and print the contents in a human readable way. There is a file that is provided along with libstdc++ which teaches GDB how to display such things. I provided you a link to the file.

Comment: OK. You said via gdb 'source' command, can you be more specific?